# SQL: Recursive search for each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm not even sure if this is possible using SQL only but here goes...

I have a list of football results in one table, each row is a match and contains all data from that match i.e. Home(team), HomeGoals, AwayGoals, Away(team), I want to cycle through each match, get the home team, check their last 6 matches and display only the matches where the specified team scored 2 goals or more in 50% or more of their last 6 matches.

So far I have this, I just don't know how to stitch it together...

Create list of all games, returning only the home team:

```
SELECT *
FROM [FDATA].[dbo].[Goals]
ORDER BY Date
```

Get last 6 games of that team: ( I want to do the following query for every row of the above query)

```
SELECT TOP 6 *
FROM [FDATA].[dbo].[Goals]
WHERE Home = '[Home] from first query'  AND Date <= '[Date] from first query'  
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Then check if the team scored 2 or more goals in >= 50% of the 6 games returned and output the row from the first query if true.

So basically for every row in the database I want to find the last 6 games of the home team in that row (game) and see if they scored 2 or more goals in 50% or more of those games, if so, output the original row, if not, omit the row from the results.

Is it possible?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL? It makes a big difference. Your syntax looks like SQL Server but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: This is definitely possible, but it's going to be pretty complicated. I hope efficiency isn't a big concern for your purposes.

Comment: you mean - get list of teams who scored 2 or more goals in 50% or more in any of 6 consequent games they played? then get all record of these teams where they were the home team?

Comment: What version of SQL Server, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2012. Not tested, but I think this should work:

```
WITH Last6 as (
  SELECT 
    Home, HomeGoals, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Home ORDER BY Goals.Date DESC) GameNumber
  FROM Goals
),
Medians as (
  SELECT 
    Home, 
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY HomeGoals) OVER (PARTITION BY Home) GoalMedian
  FROM Last6
  WHERE GameNumber <= 6
)    
SELECT *
FROM Goals G
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Medians WHERE G.Home = Medians.Home AND GoalMedian >= 2)
```

Comment: He wants every row in the first result set to display, along with statistics for each rolling set of 6 games. Your query doesn't meet these requirements.

Comment: Edited: it's even better now, as I don't need the "DISTINCT Home" anymore.

Comment: I just noticed that the OP wanted all game results, no just the last 6 for each home team, so I changed the query slightly with an EXISTS to access all of the Goals table.

Comment: Jods, this solution gives the error: "The multi-part identifier "G.Date" could not be bound." Strange though as the column & table names are correct.

Comment: My fault, I didn't alias Goals to G. It's inside the Last6 CTE, I've changed G.Date to Goals.Date. This is what happens when you don't execute your code on a real DB. ;)

Comment: Jods (or anyone!), do you know how I would make this query 'correlated', so that the last6 table is updated based on the date in the row currently being processed in the main query? At the moment it's numbering the rows from the last entry evrytime.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
WITH RankedGoals AS (
   SELECT
      *,
      Sequence = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY G.Home ORDER BY G.Date DESC)
   FROM FDATA.dbo.Goals G
)
SELECT
   G.*
FROM
   RankedGoals G
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT
         *
      FROM
         RankedGoals S
      WHERE
         G.Home = S.Home
         AND S.Sequence BETWEEN G.Sequence AND G.Sequence + 5
      HAVING
         Sum(CASE WHEN S.Goals >=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 3
         AND Count(*) = 6
   )
;
```

The query can be modified so the `EXISTS` section uses `TOP 6` with a date search instead, which may perform better as it won't have to do a windowing function. But I am not sure if the `Date` column is guaranteed unique. If so, it's easy:

```
SELECT
   G.*
FROM
   FDATA.dbo.Goals G
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT
         *
      FROM
         (
            SELECT TOP 6 *
            FROM
               FDATA.dbo.Goals S
            WHERE
               G.Home = S.Home
               AND S.Date <= G.Date
            ORDER BY
               S.Date
          ) S
      HAVING
         Sum(CASE WHEN S.Goals >=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 3
         AND Count(*) = 6
   )
;
```

I strongly recommend having an index on the `Home` and `Date` columns...

Comment: Thanks for your replies, yes I'm using SQL Server 2012. I tried the first solution above but get the error: "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: The 2nd solution gives the error: "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Comment: Sorry about the errors. I have fixed them... that'll learn me to always make a working example! :)

Comment: Cheers, still errors on s.goals though, don't worry though I'll use the solution above, cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, NULL as 50percent2ormore
FROM [FDATA].[dbo].[Goals]
INTO #tempgames
ORDER BY Date

Update #tempgames
SET 50percent2ormore = 'Yes'
FROM ( 
SELECT TOP 6 *, count('games with 2 or more goals') as count
FROM #tempgames
WHERE Home = #tempgames.home  
AND Date <= #tempgames.date
ORDER BY Date DESC 
) tmp
WHERE tmp.count >= 3

SELECT * FROM #tempgames WHERE 50percent2ormore = 'Yes'
```

This might be a place to start...

Comment: Thanks, I got a whole list of syntax errors when trying to run this though.